# Make text selection even we select it from its closing empty spaces/ padding edges

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pdftron

In pdftron, you need to make selection/ go to exact sentence and need precise selection of text to have text to be selected.
Wanted it to be less precise selection just like they have in abode reader dc. Even we close to text, the cursor change to text selection pointer, and we can select the text, even we drag straight in empty space above the text.
[image]

Comment: When you say that you would like the text selection to be less precise, can you clarify what you are referring to (ie. provide a screencap from Adobe reader)? In addition, can I ask why are you looking to have the text selection to be less precise? How does this affect how your users interact with your application?

Comment: @ShakthiWijeratne The image I posted is from Adobe Reader the exact behavior that I have described. Even that Selector is on top of text, when you drag straight in whitespace above the text, text is getting selected in Adobe. Try it.